# How to set like email signature text for every print printed by my PC and printer?

Tags: windows-xp, printer

**Edit:**

I'm on windows XP and i have laser printer. at bottom of every page i want to print my firm name **even if i take print from browser or from word file etc**. i mean from every source. is it possible to set. like email signature.

Comment: this is generally called a "page footer" or simply "footer". you'd usually add it to your *document* in a word-processing or page layout application.  i suppose it's possible to set in a printer driver such that *every* page printed gets it, but that strikes me as overkill.

Answer (score 1):

Quack is right, this is normally done with a page footer in your word processor.

Another way you could accomplish this is to pre-print a ream of paper with your firm name at the bottom of the page and then put it back in the printer ready for whatever comes out next.

Or you could buy some pre-printed stationery, which might look better.

I suppose it depends on what you're trying to achieve (evidence of the print source versus branding etc)

Answer (score 1):

Different printer manufacturers will have different options in their drivers. Open up your printers folder, right click on the printer and select printing preferences.

Look for tabs named Watermarks or Stamps/Composition or something similar. This will give the options to print overlay text/images on all pages printed.

I have some screenshots from different printers here at work:

Here is the tab from a Konica/Minolta printer:

[image: Konica/Minolta]

And from a Ricoh printer:

[image: Ricoh]

Answer (score 0):

This is definitely a task for the **Print&Share** software from **Ricoh**. Once you start using it, you'll never want to use anything else for sure!
http://www.ricoh-europe.com/products/software/output-management/printshare.aspx

This video should help you to add extra content to your document: 
http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=r7prDkHA_AY